# Where should I put an unmanaged dll dependency?

Tags: asp.net, dependencies

I have a Visual Studio solution with two projects :

- A class library `MyLib`

  - `MyLib` references `MyAssembly.dll`
  - `MyAssembly.dll` is dependent on `mynativedll.dll` which is not a .Net assembly, but a native dll.
- A web project `MyWeb`

  - `MyWeb` reference `MyAssembly.dll`

In the web project, where should I put the `mynativedll.dll` ?

If I put this dll in the bin directory, the dll is voided when cleaning.

If I put this dll, beside `MyAssembly.dll` in "Lib" folder and I add a probing path to this folder, this does not works. Actually, the `MyAssembly.dll` is copied to the bin directory (as it's a reference), even if I set "Copy to local" to true.

What are the correct way to handle such cases ?

Comment: is mynativedll.dll a COM DLL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh ... simply in fact.

I directly referenced the `MyAssembly.dll` in the web project (even I not required from a code perspective).
Then I set up "Copy local" to false in the web directory.

and that solved the problem.

The `MyAssembly.dll` is not copied to the bin folder, but red from the lib folder where the native dll also resides in.

Comment: I'm not sure that will fix your problem. I bet if you look in the `/bin` folder, you'll see an old copy of both `.dll` files. The correct answer is placing them all in `/bin`.

Comment: @Eric: no... bin is not a good place to manually place dll. But you were right, I've had to clean the bin folder for this to works.

Comment: @James Johnson: I've to wait two days

Comment: You can use project references. In the project that needs the unmanaged dll, you can add it to the project, but set the properties' window Build Action to `Content`. Then it will be copied automatically when referenced by other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you're not implementing the methods of the native library externally using the DllImport attribute?:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
private static extern int LogonUserA(String lpszUserName, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken, int impersonationLevel, ref IntPtr hNewToken);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool RevertToSelf();

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
```

DllImport attribute:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx

Extern modifier:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: both MyAssembly.dll and MyNativeLibrary.dll are 3rd party... and my problem is not how the dll works, but the dll is found

Comment: Is the native DLL provided by the OS?

Comment: of course not ! there wouldn't be any problem if it was the case